# What should we do with clearly fake questions?

Tags: discussion, support, allowed-questions, specific-question

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/357725/232393) about a "new horror steve or bug" is, as far as I can tell, not a real question about a real problem (it could, though extremely unlikely, be a mod that the author forgot about).

There is an identical question (even with the same spelling mistakes), both on [queryxchange](https://www.queryxchange.com/q/15_357725/i-found-some-sort-of-new-horror-steve-or-bug/) and [questarter](https://www.questarter.com/q/i-found-some-sort-of-new-horror-steve-or-bug-15_357725.html), uploaded at exactly the same time by a user with the same name.

It might be an attempt to make a horror story go viral, or something similar (it's the only explaination beyond "trolling" that I can think of).

So in conclusion, what should we do with questions like this, and especially with this one in particular?

- Should it be deleted as spam, or some other reason?
- Should it be closed for being off-topic, is it even off-topic?
- Should it be down voted and then ignored?

What is the correct action to take with a question like this?

Comment: It seems that both that question and [Does Herobrine exist?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/18592/4797) are both about fake things and are not real problems.

Comment: @galacticninja As I see it, the questions are different. The question I used as an example is an attempt to spread a rumor, it's a fabricated question. "Does Herobrine exist?" is a question about a rumor, it's not designed to spread a story, the question itself is (likely) real.

Comment: I think queryxchange is a scraper.  I see my newest question there and I definitely only posted to arqade.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not the first time a user has tried to start a [weird rumour about a game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creepypasta#Video_games), most commonly Minecraft. These are not actually questions and should be closed as off-topic, with  a custom reason explaining that we only accept real questions about problems relating to gaming.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that I find it a bit funny to say "most commonly Minecraft", right after a link that has a lot of examples, none of them being minecraft. This is a good answer to my question, so thank you.

Comment: Ah, you see, bad Minecraft creepypasta is *what we get*, not what is popular ;)

Comment: I think the [Herobrine](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Herobrine) myth is pretty popular. It probably should belong on the list.

Comment: @PausePause Anyone can edit Wikipedia. That said, that's all I know about Wikipedia, so you should look around a bit and learn how it works before making any edits.